Can and does any statically typed programming language safely support in-place type-conversion?
Here's some hypothetical rust-inspired language syntax to show what I mean
// I use the double-arrow "=>" to mean that calling the function changes
// the type of the argument when the function is called
fn changes_argument_type(x: &mut OldType => NewType) {
    *x = to_new_type(*x);
}

fn main() {
    let mut x: OldType = OldType::new();
    changes_argument_type(&mut x);
    // Now x has the type NewType
}

Would it be possible to safely implement such a feature and has any statically typed programming language done so? The one restriction I can think of is that the new type needs to have the same size as the old type, since it will be stored at the same memory location. As well as the pointer being unique, since otherwise we'll change the type for some other user.
Some possible use cases:

In-place updates of statically checked state machines
Applying newtypes (or other type-changing functions) to every item in array
Type narrowing
Imperative dependently-typed programs


Edit: I was asked for how it would be useful compared to current solutions
Here is an example of what a state machine can look like in rust:
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Closed;
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Open;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Door<S> {
    shared_value: u8,
    state: S
}

impl Door<Closed> {
    fn new(number: u8) -> Self {
        Door { shared_value: number, state: Closed }
    }
    fn open(&self) -> Door<Open> {
        Door { shared_value: self.shared_value, state: Open }
    }
}
impl Door<Open> {
    fn close(&self) -> Door<Closed> {
        Door { shared_value: self.shared_value, state: Closed }
    }
}
fn main() {
    let door = Door::new(0);
    println!("New door: {:?}",&door);
    let open_door = door.open();
    println!("Opened the door: {:?}",&open_door);
    let closed_door = open_door.close();
    println!("Closed the door: {:?}",&closed_door);
}

As you can see, we are forced to use a new variable name each time the door changes state, despite it semantically being the same door. If we just used an enum and ignored the extra type safety from tagging the state machine with the current state, we would for most likely want to use the same mutable variable instead of introducing new variables for each step.
With a feature like this we could have more imperative code, while still preserving the extra type safety:
impl Door<Closed> {
    fn new(number: u8) -> Self {
        Door { shared_value: number, state: Closed }
    }
    fn open(&mut self: Door<Closed> => Door<Open>) {
        self.state = Open;
    }
}
impl Door<Open> {
    fn close(&mut self: Door<Open> => Door<Closed>) {
        self.state = Closed;
    }
}
fn main() {
    let mut door = Door::new(0);
    println!("New door: {:?}",&door);
    door.open();
    println!("Opened the door: {:?}",&door);
    door.close();
    println!("Closed the door: {:?}",&door);
}

I also believe that a feature like this would supersede the concept of type-narrowing like in typescript, since it allows explicitly annotating how the type changes after a line of code is executed.
I guess my main remaining question is if there has been any research into implementing something like this in any (experimental) language?

This seems to be of dubious usefulness compared to, say, a linear function type old ⊸ new. Linear types already allow in-place updates.

@NaïmFavier In a way, this could maybe be viewed as an alternative syntax and perspective for linear types. Instead of being forced to write functional style code where each variable is immutable, you can write imperative code but have stronger guarantees.

Most things are possible, but not all things that are possible are wise.  The benefits of such a feature seem (to me) dubious at best, and the cost is more complexity.
In particular, it is easy to achieve what you want by introducing a new variable name, so the benefits of a way to do it while reusing the same name seem limited.  Also this risks making it harder to reason about code, because it violates the invariant that each variable name has the same type throughout the code, so to reason about the type of a particular variable, one first has to reason about control flow.  Finally, it means that the type of a variable depends not just on the name or the line of code where it appears, so it cannot be statically resolved, but must be resolved at runtime based on the control flow so far.
But perhaps you have an argument for why it is beneficial.

I have updated the question with an example that illustrates the value of the concept better. The main use case would be when they are semantically the same object but need different types for technical reasons, like distinguishing from potentially empty and guaranteed non-empty lists or the state machine in my example above. It could also simplify the syntax when modifying deeply nested state and make the in-place modification guarantees more explicit.
